# How to programmatically break links for Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2008

All our Crystal reports have an image (e.g. company logo). Some of these images are hard linked to a file on the local machine e.g. C:\Images\ReportLogo.bmp. I can access these links from the Crystal Reports Designer by clicking Edit > Links. On this pop up form there is a button labeled **Break Link**. How do I programmatically break the links instead of manually opening every report file and clicking the button? We have 100+ reports so I'd prefer not to go the manual route.

This is what I have so far (we use this to set the width/height of the same picture object I'm trying to break the link for:

```
Imports RAS = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer

Dim cdwReport as RAS.ReportClientDocumentWrapper
Dim crcObjects As RAS.ReportDefModel.ReportObjects = cdwReport.ReportDefController.ReportObjectController.GetAllReportObjects
Dim crcPictureObject As CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.PictureObject

For Each crcObject As RAS.ReportDefModel.ReportObject2 In crcObjects
    If crcObject.Kind = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.CrReportObjectKindEnum.crReportObjectKindPicture Then 

        crcPictureObject = crcObject
        With crcPictureObject
            .OriginalHeight = PicHeight
            .OriginalWidth = PicWidth
            'Break link here
        End With
    End If
```

`crcPictureObject.LinkedURI` is Nothing.

Not 100% sure whether this is the appropriate route to take to break all the links. The code above loops through all the reports in a folder.

Is there an "easy" way of doing this? (either VB.net/C# will be fine)